# java JarEntry getSize() returns -1

Tags: java, jar

### EDIT 3

It turns out some jar files will properly report `entry.getSize()`  with `JarStreamInput` and some don't.  All the jar files I created going back to 2013 (on OSX Java 8 and higher) work and various others like `mongo-spark-connector-10.0.0.jar` work.  Others like `antlr-runtime-4.7.2.jar`, `mongodb-driver-core-4.9.0.jar`, and `hadoop-azure-3.2.0.jar` do not.  But all files properly report size when accessed via `JarFile`.

I have a valid `JarInputStream js` sourced from a database (i.e. not using files on filesystem).  In case there are some nuances to `byte[]`, streams, and unzipping, this is how the `JarInputStream` is set up:

```
byte[] bb = get complete set of bytes; // print bb.length is 14523 so OK
ByteArrayInputStream bas = new ByteArrayInputStream(bb);
JarInputStream js = new JarInputStream(bas);
```

I iterate it in this way:

```
        JarEntry entry;
        while ((entry = js.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
            if (!entry.isDirectory() && entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                String className = entry.getName().replace('/', '.').substring(0, entry\
.getName().length() - 6);
                                
                long len = entry.getSize();
                long zlen = entry.getCompressedSize();

                System.out.println("  class [" + className + "]: Z " + zlen + "; unZ " + len);

                if(len > 0) {
                    byte[] classBytes = new byte[len];
                    js.read(classBytes);

                    System.out.println("captured [" + className + "]");
                    classBytesMap.put(className, classBytes);
               }

        ...
```

The loop "works" because it correctly pulls all the class names out so it is clearly walking the input stream properly.  However, both `entry.getSize()` and `entry.getCompressedSize` are always -1.  This is openjdk version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18.

The javadoc states that -1 means the size is unknown but there must be a size or some other means by which to process just this entry before moving further down the stream.

I am not wed to this approach; the ultimate goal is to walk a `JarInputStream` and extract classname-classbyte entries.

### EDIT

As a test, the `byte[] bb` array is written back to file `XX2.jar` and then examined using regular `JarFile` classes.  This *works*:

```
        JarFile jf = new JarFile("XX2.jar");
        for (java.util.Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jf.entries(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
            entry = e.nextElement();
            if (!entry.isDirectory() && entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                String className = entry.getName().replace('/', '.').substring(0, entry\
.getName().length() - 6);
                int x = (int)entry.getSize();
                int cx = (int)entry.getCompressedSize();
                System.out.println("  class [" + className + "]: Z " + cx + "; unZ " + \
x);
            }
        }

  class [org.bson.AbstractBsonReader$1]: Z 506; unZ 792
  class [org.bson.AbstractBsonReader$Context]: Z 497; unZ 1227
  class [org.bson.AbstractBsonReader$Mark]: Z 813; unZ 2201
```

However, trying to read that file using a regular `FileInputStream` as we see in many other SO examples does **not work**:

```
      JarInputStream jarInputStream = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream("XX2.jar"));

      loop runs but size and compressedSize are STILL -1.
```

### EDIT 2

Here is a complete example that demos the problem:

```
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarInputStream;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class jartest {
    public static void showEntry(JarEntry entry) {
        if (!entry.isDirectory() && entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
            String className = entry.getName().replace('/', '.').substring(0, entry.get\
Name().length() - 6);
            int x = (int)entry.getSize();
            int cx = (int)entry.getCompressedSize();
            System.out.println("  class [" + className + "]: Z " + cx + "; unZ " + x);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JarEntry entry;

            String fname = "XX2.jar";

            // THIS WORKS                                                               
            JarFile jf = new JarFile(fname);
            for (java.util.Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jf.entries(); e.hasMoreElements();\
) {
        entry = e.nextElement();
                showEntry(entry);
            }

            // THIS DOES NOT WORK                                                       
            JarInputStream js = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(fname));
            while ((entry = js.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
        showEntry(entry);
            }

    } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("fail: " + e);
        }
    }
}

$ java jartest
  class [grun$ExecutionContextImpl]: Z 706; unZ 1245
  class [grun]: Z 3210; unZ 6476
  class [grun$ExecutionContextImpl]: Z -1; unZ -1
  class [grun]: Z -1; unZ -1
```

Any clues?  Overall it looks like streams are not working but filename based logic does work.

Comment: according javadoc, -1 means size is unknown

Comment: `bb` would have to contain a *valid and complete* jar file

Comment: @g00se  It does.   If I add
`            java.nio.file.Files.write(java.nio.file.Paths.get("XX2.jar"), bb); `
then a valid jar file is produce.   `jar tvf XX2.jar` works, `unzip -l XX2.jar` works, etc.

Comment: I don't see any code making use of those length variables. Can you put that in the question?

Comment: @g00se  Done.   I am continuing to tinker with this.

Comment: Yes, but you gave the *output* from the file but not from the stream

Answer (score 1):

According to the javadoc, -1 means that the respective size is unknown.

According to the source code, the values of a ZipEntry / JarEntry's  size fields are read from the ZIP or JAR file itself.  The logic is a bit complicated<sup>1</sup>, but immediate explanation for getting a -1 is that the code was unable to extract sizes from the LOC header, or because the sizes were -1 in the LOC header.

To figure out what is actually going on in *your* case, you will need to decode the JAR file's headers by hand.  Note that a JAR file is actually a ZIP file with a manifest, so you can use the format description in the [ZIP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)) Wikipedia page as a reference.

As suggested by [@g00se's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16376827/g00se) comment, the problem *could* be that the JAR file you are trying to read is incomplete or malformed.  So another alternative would be to write the bytes to a file and see if a ZIP tool or the `jar` command can read the file.

---

<sup>1 - Classic ZIP and ZIP64 represent the sizes differently in the LOC headers.  The `ZipEntry` code has to unpick this.</sup>

Comment: See comment above.   Writing the `byte[] bb` back out yields a well-formed jar.   All the correct bytes are there.